# What's a good way to bundle and add a whole bunch of JARs into a maven project?

Tags: java, maven

...without specifying each and every one as a separate dependency?

So I have to work with a whole bunch of java dependencies provided by a proprietary third party software in the form of a downloadable SDK. I really want to use maven for dependency and lifecycle management, but also can't be bothered to add several dozens of JARs as individual dependencies. What's the most elegant solution to work around this issue?

Comment: Create a separate POM file which depends on all your SDK jars. You can let the version of this POM file follow the version number of the SDK. In  your project you only have to depend on this POM. It is described as BOM (Bill Of Material): https://howtodoinjava.com/maven/maven-bom-bill-of-materials-dependency/

Comment: @Conffusion It is useful to have a POM with common dependencies, but this is not the same as a BOM. A BOM is for dependencyManagement.

Answer (score 2):

Each jar must be added as a `<dependency>` *somewhere*.

So if you have just one project that uses 100 JARs as dependencies, you need to add all those dependencies (each as a `<dependency>`) entry.

If you have several projects using the same JARs, I would follow Conffusion's advice to create a POM with the dependencies and then use that POM in all the projects.

Maven cannot add "a directory of JARs" to the dependencies.

Comment: Well... gues I'll be writing a couple of lines to generate a huge pom file for the 500 JARs...

Comment: @Michael, Are you sure no one else has done this already before ? maven will load automatically defined dependencies of your dependencies but I can imagine finding out which subset you need to add can even be harder than just add all.